# Как изменить положение и иконку toolbar в android studio?

Tags: android

В данный момент всё выглядит примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо изменить иконку и изменить положение на такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код из активити:

```
    globalvariables.toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    globalvariables.toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    setSupportActionBar(globalvariables.toolbar);
```

Comment: Если не занудствовать по поводу того, что непонятно зачем вам такой дизайн, то на вскидку решение такое:
- Добавить отдельный toolbar внутрь активити (в контент)
- У главного toolbar (полагаю это AppBar) убрать все Action'ы и перенести их во второй (внутренний toolbar)

Comment: @JustAnotherCoder системные компоненты экшенбара нельзя перенести в простой тулбар

Comment: вы не можете разделить toolbar, назначенный экшенбаром на два тулбара, чтобы оба они выполняли часть функций экшенбара (системная кнопка "назад", заголовок активити, системная кнопка "overflow" в которую помещаются не вошедшие пункты системного меню). Экшенбаром может быть назначен только один тулбар

Comment: @pavlofff ну судя по картинкам, кнопка назад и заголовок не нужны, а вот меню, в таком случае, придется самому ручками делать, но это не так уж и сложно по идее

Comment: @JustAnotherCoder это будет не то меню (не системное OptionMenu) и не та кнопка overflow (которая вмещает в себя не вошедшие на экран и скрытые пункты меню опций)